# Executing Bash script: ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near

Tags: bash, postgresql

I get an error while executing the following psql statement inside a bash script:

```
execlog "psql -h $HOST -p $PORT -U $USER -d $DB -q -c 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'"
```

The raised error is:

> ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'CREATE"
>   LINE 1: 'CREATE
>           ^

Thus, the single terminating quote is not recognize as it should be.
When using escaped double quotes instead single quotes (...\"CREATE EXTENSION hstore;\") I get the same error.
When executing the command directly from the command line, everything works fine.

Does someone know what's going wrong?

To give some additional info:

OS: Ubuntu 11.10, Postgresql Verion: 9.1

Thanks in advance,
Richard

**Solved:** The execlog function produces the error. Now I am calling

```
log "exec psql -h $HOST -p $PORT -U $USER -d $DB -q -c 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'"
```

which works fine!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: for bash debugging `set -x`, this will write to stderr the command being executed. then you can see what gets passed to psql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after quote removal, the single quotes are no longer treated as syntax to escape the space, but literal characters as part of the string. Try

```
execlog psql -h $HOST -p $PORT -U $USER -d $DB -q -c 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore;'
```

(I can't find any information on `execlog`, so I don't know if the above will work.)

Comment: Thanks for your pointer to execlog (an own function in our library). This produces the error...